# getBoundingClientRect().x of lastChild

Tags: javascript, html, css, getboundingclientrect

my current code working perfectly:

CSS:

```
#center
{
    background:#781111;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    width:100px;
}

#c
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    background:yellow;
    color:#781111;
    width:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="center">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="a">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
alert(document.getElementById('center').getBoundingClientRect().x);
```

Now, Up until this point everything working perfectly but when I try to fetch the lastChild (div#c) like this:

```
alert(document.getElementById('center').lastChild.getBoundingClientRect().x);
```

It's not working properly.

Here is my jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hezi_gangina/3m2n9otr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the last children element you should use lastElementChild and to get the x position of BoundingClientRect get left property like:

```
var xLastChild = document.getElementById('center').lastElementChild.getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/3m2n9otr/5/

Answer (score 4):

First issue: `lastChild` returns any node, not just HTML tag elements.  The last child of `#center` is a `Text` node (containing `&nbsp;`), not an `Element`, so it does not have a `getBoundingClientRect` method.  You can select `#c` like so:

```
document.querySelector('#center > *:last-child')
```

Second issue: the result of `getBoundingClientRect` does not have an `x` field.  You can use `left` instead:

```
document.querySelector('#center > *:last-child').getBoundingClientRect().left
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3m2n9otr/2/